# startNodeManager.sh not found

Tags: docker, weblogic

I have been trying to run Oracle weblogic in Docker containers and i am facing trouble in starting the NodeManager.I ran the following command.

```
docker run -d --name MS1 --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin -p 8001:8001 -e ADMIN_PASSWORD=#123 \
           -e MS_NAME=MS1 --volumes-from wlsadmin a5e55 createServer.sh
```

Under normal circumstances it is expected to start the Nodemanager.

I am able to access the weblogic console and start the Managed Server which then returns the error-

-- Warning For server MS1, the Node Manager associated with machine Machine_MS1 is not reachable

This is the part of the log file that is returned on executing the above "`docker run`" command :

```
Domain Home:  /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain
Managed Server Name:  MS1
NodeManager Name: 
       ----> 'weblogic' admin password: ctebs#123
Waiting for WebLogic Admin Server on wlsadmin:7001 to become available...
WebLogic Admin Server is now available. Proceeding...
Setting NodeManager
       ----> No NodeManager Name set
Node Manager Name:  Machine_MS1
Node Manager Home for Container:  /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1
cp: cannot stat '/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain /bin/startNodeManager.sh': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/nodemanager/*': No such file or directory
NODEMGR_HOME_STR:  NODEMGR_HOME="/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1"
NODEMGRHOME_STR:  NodeManagerHome=/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1
DOMAINSFILE_STR:  DomainsFile=/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1/nodemanager.domains
LOGFILE_STR:  LogFile=/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1/nodemanager.log
sed: can't read /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1/startNodeManager.sh: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1/nodemanager.properties: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1/nodemanager.properties: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain/Machine_MS1/nodemanager.properties: No such file or directory
Starting NodeManager in background...
NodeManager started.
Connection refused (Connection refused). Could not connect to  NodeManager. Check that it is running at /172.17.0.3:5556.
Starting server MS1 ...No stack trace available.
This Exception occurred at Tue Dec 12 03:38:06 GMT 2017.
weblogic.management.scripting.ScriptException: Error occurred while   performing start : Server with name MS1 failed to be started
No stack trace available.
```

How can I get past this error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and follow this [OracleWebLogic workshop intro](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleWebLogic/workshops/intro/README.md) which points out:

> The **[`~/docker-images/OracleWebLogic/samples/1221-domain/container-scripts`](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/69a2db3f7957a8f3a7ee3dfec3e30de7f7bfb5aa/OracleWebLogic/samples/1221-domain)** has useful Bash and WLST scripts that provide three possible modes to run WebLogic Managed Servers on a Docker container. Make sure you have an AdminServer container running before starting a ManagedServer container.
>
> The sample scripts will by default, attempt to find the AdminServer running at `t3://wlsadmin:8001`. You can change this.
>   But most importantly, the AdminServer container has to be linked with Docker's `--link` parameter.
>
> Below, are the three suggestions for running ManagedServer Container within the sample 12c-domain:
>
> Start NodeManager (Manually):
>
> ```
> docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin startNodeManager.sh
> ```
>
> Start NodeManager and Create a Machine Automatically:
>
> ```
> docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin createMachine.sh
> ```
>
> Start NodeManager, Create a Machine, and Create a ManagedServer Automatically
>
> ```
> docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin createServer.sh
> ```

See more at "[Example of Image with WLS Domain](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/69a2db3f7957a8f3a7ee3dfec3e30de7f7bfb5aa/OracleWebLogic/samples/1221-domain)", removed in [commit e49bb4d](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/commit/e49bb4d070de9ba8dcd5f5c718c93a1f77b498f6) in Apr. 2019, 2 yers later, since Oracle no longer supports WebLogic versions.

Comment: that works fine for 12.2.1 but other 12.2.1.2 is not working for me

Comment: @AmalVijayan Then probably a bug to report to https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues

Comment: Link at the end of the answer is dead.

Comment: @jannis Thank you. I have restored the link.